# After upgrade to 20.04 Nautilus has become slow

Tags: 18.04, gnome, 20.04, nautilus

I've just recently updated from 18.04 to 20.04 and have started noticing some drastic changes in how Nautilus behaves.

Any gui invoke of Nautilus (directly by me or from a third party application) will in most cases take 20-25 seconds to respond with a Nautilus window being shown. Afterwards there seems to be some grace period where this does not happen, counted in minutes.

My disks are in perfect order (SSDs) with IO not being an issue (tested through terminal) and nothing (I can recall) has changed on the system apart from the version upgrade.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

**Update 1:**

Removing nautilus has not had any effect on this behaviour as it also seems to happen to Nemo, which I installed to check for variability in behaviour.

I've also noted that without fault it takes 25 seconds to start Nautilus. Which is a strange consistency in the behaviour.

Comment: My Nautilus works fine after the upgrade, and I prefer it over Nemo, which I used for a long time. After finding that Nemo doesn't generate thumbnails I found a solution, one of the steps was to switch to Nautilus. Since implementing it, Nautilus comes up in an instant but might take some time to regenerate the thumbnails. The only suggestion that I have is to remove nautilus and re-install.

Comment: Noted. We have to look for a different underlying cause in this case. I will get back if I come up with something. In the meantime please try other applications to see if they exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has now been remedied and I believe the culprit was a Nautilus extension by Dropbox. At least everything behaves well again after removing it.

Comment: Great You can accept your answer as the solution, that way it will help anyone else in the community.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem related to  `libssl1.0.0` (it seems to be related to nautilus via `gvfs-afc-volume-monitor`)

Looking into the syslog,

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep libssl
```

I got errors of the kind:

`gvfs-afc-volume-monitor[5102]: /usr/libexec/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

**To fix this, I installed `libssl1.0-dev`, with**

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

which also installed `libssl1.0.0`.

You may find that you are unable to unstall `libssl1.1.0`, getting an error of the kind `Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate`.

In that case, you can add the repo manually (Using the repository for 18.04 since `libssl1.1.0` was dropped in 20.04)

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list
```

Update and check that it is now available

```
sudo apt update
apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
```

and then install with

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```